# Get all the frames in the currently active tab in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get a list of all the frameIds within the currently active tab, from the popup script?

Ideally, I would also like to be notified if a frame is added or removed.

Comment: 1) chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames, 2) an event from chrome.webRequest with a filter parameter like `types: ['sub_frame']`

Comment: webRequest? what if the dom changes dynamically? im currently thinking i need a mutationobserver in the content script that notifies the popup, which then calls getAllFrames again?

Comment: Yes, iframes are reported by those APIs.

Comment: but which do I add a listener to if an iframe is removed from the dom?

Comment: Oh, I've missed that part of the question. Indeed, you'll need a content script with MutationObserver for that.

Comment: alright, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `webNavigation` permission and 3 APIs:

### Get the current frames

`chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames(tabId)`

### Detect added frames

`chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(fn)`

In the `fn` function you'd have to filter by `tabId`.

### Detect removed frames

`chrome.runtime.connect()`

After injecting a content script into the frame, use this API to connect to your popup and then listen to the `onDisconnect` event to find out when the frame is destroyed.

I don't think that there's an easy way to listen to removed frames. The MutationObserver method still requires injecting multiple content scripts and using messaging, so you might as well just use `runtime.connect()`